Can't identify logo for a 135N68A MOSFET. Hunting for datasheet. Any ideas?
This MOSFET was inside an unbranded Chinese made PWM solar charge controller with no model number:


It's helpful to indicate some measurements and or the package involved.

Since that looks like a TO-220 housing, I searched for "135N68A TO-220" and found this datasheet.
The logo matches as does the part number.  The company is Wuxi Unigroup Microelectronics CO.,LTD.

\$V_{DS}\$ 68V
\$I_D\$ 135A


It’s made by Wuxi Unigroup, P/N TTB135N68A
